# Which tools i can use to query the data stored on elasticSearch and generate an alert on top of those query

Tags: elasticsearch, prometheus, elastalert2

I want to query TB's of data stored on elasticSearch and generate around 500 alert on top of that query. I need a plugin or some free source tool to achieve this.
Can prometheus and ElastAlert help me in achieving this, if not then which tool?

Answer (score 0):

ElastAlert is the tool i was looking for.
Following is the description and reference link.

ElastAlert 2 is a simple framework for alerting on anomalies, spikes, or other patterns of interest from data in Elasticsearch and OpenSearch.

If you have data being written into Elasticsearch in near real time and want to be alerted when that data matches certain patterns, ElastAlert 2 is the tool for you.

https://elastalert2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/elastalert.html